# Buy and taste tea in China

Tags: china, shopping

I'm collecting places where I could taste and buy tea in China during my trip. Currently I have Beijing, Xian,Shanhai, HK on my road map, but if you have information about good and not scam tea in other cities, please let me know.

I'm interested in middle price level Phuer, Oolong and White Tea.

Comment: Are you looking to head out to where it is grown to try+buy, or somewhere in one of the cities with a variety to try?

Comment: China is rather a large country with many, many towns and cities.  It'd be great if it could be limited to your route for the purpose of answers.

Answer (score 3):

In Shanghai, there is [Tianshan Tea City](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g308272-d2312338-Reviews-Tianshan_Tea_City-Shanghai.html).  This is not far from the Zhongshan Park metro station.  Also, the Cloud 9 shopping mall, which is directly accessible from that station, has a Carrefour where you can get decent tea at cheap prices.

The local teas in that region are green teas, however – Long Jing, Bi Luo Chun and others.  There is some oolong, especially Tie Guanyin (Iron Goddess).  If you’re looking for pu’er cha, why not go to Yunnan?  The markets in Dali and Lijiang are full of shops selling the stuff, and you could certainly get it in Kunming as well.  Below is a video of a Lijiang teashop that many tour groups visit:

[Yunpu tianxia teashop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkFZCXr4NIQ)

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the area of Sichuan, there is small town east of Chengdu that has a great tea place right on the lake. It's about 8 to 10 rmb and you can drink all day. It's out in the open too so you don't need to worry about scams.